# Fade out animation in wpf tabcontrol

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, tabcontrol

On a tabcontrol, I have no problem for fade in since the steps are simple. We could put a trigger in the user control and the animation goes on as soon as it becomes visible. But the problem is, when I want to fade out, the control is now hidden and therefore it cannot complete it's animation.

Here's the example that I want to achieve: http://www.yoyonetwork.info/YoYoTabTestTestPage.html

And here's the code:

```
    <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="TabControl1">
        <TabItem Width="70" Name="TabItem1">
            <Grid>
                <my:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControl1"/> <!-- my is the clr-namespace for usercontrols -->
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Width="100" Name="TabItem2">
            <Grid>                    
                <my:UserControl2 x:Name="UserControl2"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

In user controls:

```
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
```

Comment: Now I have discovered that the problem exists with all other items too. The previous item fails to fade out when a new item is getting animated with fade in. The example is animation of the keyboard focus on each element. Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that from styles. You have to manually redefine TabControl, check for its SelectionChanged event, run animation from code and wait for its Completed event to change selectedIndex.

Comment: Something like `<TabControl.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
            </TabControl.Triggers>`? And write the fade animation inside and target the usercontrolname?

Comment: No, more like custom tabControl since tabControl doesn't have Changing or Preview events for index change.

Comment: Please give me more specific guide for custom tabcontrol. Do you mean that I should create a control template or a custom event or something alike? Actually I don't know How to write a custom event.

Comment: You should write own TabControl. See this project for example: http://fabtab.codeplex.com/